# How to reset Google OAuth2 after error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-signin, google-api-js-client

I have set login to my application within the organization which is working fine as on logging in from other account prompts an error **'Error 403: org_internal'**. But the problem is it get logged in to the chrome and from the next time when I try to login it just prompt the same error without asking for credentials.

I have tried calling **signOut()** method but it doesn't seems working.

How can I reset the OAuth2 instance so that it ask for credentials in case of any error?

Initializing function which resolved google Auth:

```
googleAuth = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: ****,
                scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters'
            });
```

Signing in to google:

```
initClient().then(function (googleAuth) {
            $scope.googleAuth = googleAuth
            return googleAuth.signIn();
}
```

Error: [image]

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Comment: @DaImTo: I have edited, Please check.

Answer (score 0):

## Your error message

> client is restricted to users within its organization.

Means that this app has been set to Internal when the client was created in Google developer console.

[image]

Internal apps can only be accessed by users on the Google WorkSpace domain  use another user to login or set your project to external.

## How to signout a user

As for signing out a user The following should help

```
<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
<script>
  function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
      console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }
</script>
```

Code shamelessly ripped from [sign_out_a_user](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#sign_out_a_user)

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried to sign out using same method but still after cancelling the popup on trying again it shows the same message without asking for credentials. Also FYI, the user is not logged in yet maybe thats why signOut() is not wokring.

Comment: Check the first part of my answer that user cant login they aren't part of the gsuite domain (google workspace).  Pick a user with a workspace domain email address to login.  You might also want to double check that the domain registered in your project on Google developer console as well.

Comment: I understood that and it is working fine. I just want to reset once user close the popup so that he can login on next attempt with correct credentials.